# Cant get user name discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am making a bot for my favorite twitch streamer and medium length story short, I need a profile function for the bot. It works when you don't @ someone in the second argument, but I want people to be able to see another users profile.

```
async def profile(ctx, user=None):
  if user:
    user = discord.User.display_name
  else:
    user = ctx.message.author.name
    
  with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
    file = json.load(f)

  await ctx.send(f'PP: ``{file[user]}``')
```

users.json looks like this:
[image: users.json]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code at its current stage is quite confusing. Let me explain:

- You have no method of properly accessing your user, instead calling an empty object.
- You're using two separate ways to get the name, via `name` and `display_name`, which are two separate names. Adding to this, this method does not take into account that two users may have the same name.

You can define [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member) within the command itself. If there is no user mentioned, this will default to the command author, `ctx.author` (which is the same as `ctx.message.author`).

In the code below, you will notice two ways of I have defined the variable `user_info`. If you're going to access the numbers based on a discord user's name, I would highly recommend replacing the name with the user id so you can access other discord user information via [`get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member) or similar. Otherwise, feel free to continue using `user.name`.

Do view the revised code below.

```py
async def profile(ctx, user:discord.Member=None):
    if not user:
        user = ctx.author

    # either continue to save with the name..
    user_info = user.name # or user.display_name but don't use both!
    # ..or save with their user id
    user_info = str(user.id)

    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        file = json.load(f)

    await ctx.send(f'PP: ``{file[user_info]}``')
```